# cannot convert type T to PlayFabResult<T>

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, async-await, task, playfab

I am using the [Unity PlayFab SDK](https://github.com/PlayFab/UnitySDK) and wanting to convert the provided async callback style API to use async/await to make the code more readable.
I am trying to write a generic method to wrap any arbitrary API call into a Task.
I am very close to getting this working, but can't figure out how to set the error property on the error callback.

Here's my example:

```
public static class PFAsyncWorks
{
    public delegate void PlayFabMethod<TIn, TOut>( TIn r, Action<TOut> o , Action<PlayFabError> e, object c, Dictionary<string, string> h);
 
    public static Task<TOut> Run<TIn, TOut>( PlayFabMethod<TIn,TOut> playfabMethod,
        TIn request, object customData = null, Dictionary<string, string> extraHeaders = null )
    {
        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<TOut>();
 
        Action<TOut> resultCallback = result => tcs.SetResult( result );
        void errorCallback(PlayFabError error)
        {
           
            var ret = default(TOut);
            //THIS LINE GIVES ERROR - WORKS IF I COMMENT IT OUT BUT THEN ERRORS ARE SWALLOWED
            ((PlayFabResult<TOut>)ret).Error = error;
            tcs.SetResult(ret);
        }

        playfabMethod.Invoke( request, resultCallback, errorCallback, customData, extraHeaders );
 
        return tcs.Task;
    }
}
```

This (almost) works great like this:

```
    var confirm = await PFAsyncWorks.Run<ConfirmPurchaseRequest, ConfirmPurchaseResult>(
                 PlayFabClientAPI.ConfirmPurchase, new ConfirmPurchaseRequest() {OrderId = "sd"} );
```

This works great, now I can call any of the PlayFab APIs (which all follow the same paradigm of request, PlayFabResponse.
But I want to be able to handle the error callback properly.
Does anyone know how I can cast the TOut object like I am trying to above so I can set the Error property?

I get the error "The type 'TOut' cannot be used as type parameter 'TResult' in the generic type or method 'PlayFabResult'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'TOut' to 'PlayFab.SharedModels.PlayFabResultCommon'.

I have tried adding 'Where', but I still get issues

```
    public static Task<TOut> Run<TIn, TOut>( PlayFabMethod<TIn,TOut> playfabMethod,
        TIn request, object customData = null, Dictionary<string, string> extraHeaders = null )
        where TIn : PlayFabRequestCommon where TOut :  PlayFabResult<TOut>, new()
    {
        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<TOut>();
        
        try
        {

            void resultCallback(TOut result)
            {
                tcs.TrySetResult(result);// TrySetResult(result);
            }

            void errorCallback(PlayFabError error)
            {
                Debug.LogError(error.GenerateErrorReport());
                
                TOut t = new TOut();
                
                t.Error = error;
                
                tcs.TrySetResult(t);//new TOut { Error = error });
            }

            playfabMethod.Invoke(request, resultCallback, errorCallback, customData, extraHeaders);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            //tcs.TrySetException(new Exception(error.GenerateErrorReport())
            tcs.TrySetException(ex);
        }
        
        return tcs.Task;
    }
}
```

This version gives the error 'The type 'TOut' cannot be used as type parameter 'TResult' in the generic type or method 'PlayFabResult'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'TOut' to 'PlayFab.SharedModels.PlayFabResultCommon'

Thanks for any help!

Comment: *"This line gives an error"*, of course, `foo` isn't declared anywhere.

Comment: It would be so good if you posted a [mcve]. I've copy and pasted your current code and it's just a sea of errors.

Comment: @Enigmativity it is actually minimal reproducible if you import the `Unity PlayFab SDK` which OP properly linked into your Unity project and paste OPs code into a script ;)

Comment: How is this related to `async-await`? Does it work if it's not async?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you do

```
where TOut : PlayFabResult<TOut>
```

if you think about it, it makes no sense since this basically means e.g. (I know the types make no sense - it is for clarification only)

```
where int : PlayFabResult<int>
```

=> What you want here is to limit the `TOut` to `PlayFabResult<TResult>` and then further limit that `TResult` to `PlayFabResultCommon`.

You might rather need to wrap this further in another generic and do e.g.

```
public static Task<TOut> Run<TIn, TOut, TResult>(PlayFabMethod<TIn,TOut> playfabMethod, TIn request, object customData = null, Dictionary<string, string> extraHeaders = null) 
    where TIn : PlayFabRequestCommon 
    where TOut : PlayFabResult<TResult>, new()
    where TResult : PlayFabResultCommon
```

---

However, I just imported the package and there are more issues with your approach:

1. There simply is no property/field `Error` in `PlayFabReslt<T>`
2. Not all the playfab results actually inherit from `PlayfabResult<TResult>`!

   E.g. `LoginResult` directly inherits from `PlayFabResultCommon`, skipping the `PlayfabResult<TResult>`.

   **Actually** I didn't find **ANY** whatsoever ^^

For 2) you will need a different overload which actually kinda works like your first approach with only two generic types for the request and the result.

For 1) (and finally combining it all) I would simply introduce a wrapper type around the results like e.g.

```
public abstract class PlayFabResultWithError
{
    public PlayFabError Error { get; }

    protected PlayFabResultWithError(PlayFabError error)
    {
        Error = error;
    }
}

// This one is for the PlayFabResult<TResult> values
public class PlayFabResultWithError<TResult, TResultInner> : PlayFabResultWithError 
    where TResult : PlayFabResult<TResultInner> 
    where TResultInner : PlayFabResultCommon
{
    public TResult Result { get; }
    
    public PlayFabResultWithError(TResult result) : base(null)
    {
        Result = result;
    }
    
    public PlayFabResultWithError(PlayFabError error) : base(error) { }
}

// This one is for all the more generic PlayFabResultCommon values
public class PlayFabResultWithError<TResult> : PlayFabResultWithError 
    where TResult : PlayFabResultCommon
{
    public TResult Result { get; }

    public PlayFabResultWithError(TResult result) : base(null)
    {
        Result = result;
    }

    public PlayFabResultWithError(PlayFabError error) : base(error) { }
}
```

and then change your methods to

```
public delegate void PlayFabMethod<in TIn, out TResult>(TIn r, Action<TResult> o, Action<PlayFabError> e, object c = null, Dictionary<string, string> h = null);

// This one handles PlayFabResult<TResult>
public static async Task<PlayFabResultWithError<TOut, TResult>> Run<TIn, TOut, TResult>(PlayFabMethod<TIn, TOut> playfabMethod, TIn request, object customData = null, Dictionary<string, string> extraHeaders = null)
    where TIn : PlayFabRequestCommon
    where TResult : PlayFabResultCommon
    where TOut : PlayFabResult<TResult>
{
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<PlayFabResultWithError<TOut, TResult>>();

    try
    {
        void resultCallback(TOut result)
        {
            tcs.TrySetResult(new PlayFabResultWithError<TOut, TResult>(result));
        }

        void errorCallback(PlayFabError error)
        {
            Debug.LogError(error.GenerateErrorReport());

            tcs.TrySetResult(new PlayFabResultWithError<TOut, TResult>(error));
        }

        playfabMethod.Invoke(request, resultCallback, errorCallback, customData, extraHeaders);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        tcs.TrySetException(ex);
    }

    return await tcs.Task;
}

// This one handles more generic PlayFabResultCommon
public static async Task<PlayFabResultWithError<TResult>> Run<TIn, TResult>(PlayFabMethod<TIn, TResult> playfabMethod, TIn request, object customData = null, Dictionary<string, string> extraHeaders = null)
    where TIn : PlayFabRequestCommon
    where TResult : PlayFabResultCommon
{
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<PlayFabResultWithError<TResult>>();

    try
    {
        void resultCallback(TResult result)
        {
            tcs.TrySetResult(new PlayFabResultWithError<TResult>(result));
        }

        void errorCallback(PlayFabError error)
        {
            Debug.LogError(error.GenerateErrorReport());

            tcs.TrySetResult(new PlayFabResultWithError<TResult>(error));
        }

        playfabMethod.Invoke(request, resultCallback, errorCallback, customData, extraHeaders);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        tcs.TrySetException(ex);
    }

    return await tcs.Task;
}
```

---

Now you can do e.g.

```
var req = new InsightsEmptyRequest();
var details = await Example.Run<InsightsEmptyRequest, InsightsGetDetailsResponse>(PlayFabInsightsAPI.GetDetails, req);

var req2 = new LoginWithEmailAddressRequest();
var login = await Example.Run<LoginWithEmailAddressRequest, LoginResult>(PlayFabClientAPI.LoginWithEmailAddress, req2);
```

Comment: It's fine to do `where TOut : PlayFabResult<TOut>`. Try `class PlayFabResult<T> { } class Child : PlayFabResult<Child> { } class Foo<TOut> where TOut : PlayFabResult<TOut> { } void Main() { var z = new Foo<Child>(); }`.

Comment: "This would require some sort of looped inheritances" - No, it does not.

Comment: @Enigmativity yeah maybe my wording was wrong once again ... it is possible .. theoretically .. but makes 0 sense here as OP is interested in the stored `result` of the `public class PlayFabResult<TResult> where TResult : PlayFabResultCommon { public TResult result; public object customData; }`

Comment: @derHugo, this is amazing, thank you so much for your help. One thing though is I'm struggling to make a call with this solution, can you share an example of how to use it now with the third type parameter? BTW, I added "public PlayFabError Error" myself directly to the PlayFabResult<TResult> class in SharedModels.cs, so I am trying to use your first suggested answer, although I guess I could use the wrapper as well which is kind of nice to not have to modify the library.

Comment: @derHugo  I get "cannot convert to method group..." error complaining about the first parameter of the delegate now " var lin = await PFAsyncFinal.Run<LoginWithCustomIDRequest,PlayFabResult<LoginResult>, LoginResult >(
                     PlayFabClientAPI.LoginWithCustomID, req); "

Comment: @user3010678 well ... I checked once again the source code and => `LoginResult` does not inherit from `PlayFabResult<TResult>` so your method in general won't work with that one! It directly inherits from `PlayFabResultCommon` which is the common base also for `PlayFabResult<TResult>` .... you will need an overload for covering those cases I guess

Comment: hi @derHugo, you are correct. I probably asked my question poorly, but I dont think I ever needed a PlayFabResult<TError> version, just the PlayFabResultCommon verison, which allows me to create PlayFabResult<Foo>'s everywhere anyway. I was able to remove that xtra methd and xtra parent class. I want to really thank you again, this is truly a brillian and elegant solution that is really non trivial, well done man. Thank you.

Comment: @derHugo By the way, do you think an additional try/catch is needed to wrap the entire internal of the Run function? The catch would do "return Task.FromException...()) (see https://deaddesk.top/don't-fall-for-TaskCompletionSource-traps/). Also, why did you make it async compared to my OP? Just curious the advantage of making it async?

Comment: @user3010678 without it being `async` I couldn't `await` it. The exception mainly depends on: Do any of the methods you are going to invoke throw exceptions? If not I would claim this is redundant